# NoReverseMatch at /teacher_dashboard/4 Reverse for 'updateorder' not found. 'updateorder' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

**urls.py**

```
 path('teacher_dashboard/<str:id>', views.TeacherDashboard , name='teacher_dashboard'),
 path('student_dashboard//<str:id>', views.StudentDashboard , name='student_dashboard'),
```

**views.py**

```
def Login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        # print(request.POST)
        user = authenticate(request , username=username , password=password)
        if user is not None:
            try:
                is_teacher= Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)
            except Teacher.DoesNotExist:
                is_teacher = None
            if is_teacher is not None:
                login(request , user)
                is_teacher= Teacher.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)
                return redirect( 'teacher_dashboard', user.id)
            else:
                login(request , user)
                student= Student.objects.get(profile_id=user.id)
                return render(request ,'pages/student_dashboard.html' ) 
    return render (request , "pages/login.html")


def TeacherDashboard(request , id):
    is_teacher= Teacher.objects.get(profile_id = id)
    students=Student.objects.all()
    print(students)
    context={
        'student' : students
    }
    return render (request , "pages/teacher_dashboard.html" , context)
```

**teacher_dahboard.html**

```
{% for student in student %}

{{student}}

{%endfor %}
```

**teacher_dashboard.html**

```
{% extends 'pages/main.html'%}
{% block content%}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body total-orders">
            <h5>Teacher : {{teacher.first_name }} {{teacher.last_name}}</h5>
            <hr>
            <p>First Name:<b>{{teacher.first_name }}</b></p>
            <p>Last Name: <b>{{teacher.last_name }}</b></p>
            <p>Qualifications: <b>{{teacher.qualifications }}</b></p>
            <p>Gender: <b>{{teacher.teacher_gender }}</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="card card-body total-orders">
            <h5 style="text-align: center;">Contact Information</h5>
            <hr>
            <p>Email: <b>{{teacher.email}}</b></p>
            <p>Phone: <b>{{teacher.teacher_contact}}</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{% for student in student %}
{{student.first_name}}
{%endfor %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md" >
        <div class="card card-body total-orders">
            <h5>Students Information</h5>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                {% for studen in student %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{order.product}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.first_name}} {{student.last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.student_contact}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.student_grade}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.student_gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{student.created_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.status}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'updateorder' order.id%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'deleteorder' order.id%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

that's my code plz help if you can
in the teacher_dashbard/4 is dynamic route so the id came from there as 4 
i want to render the students list on teacher_dashboard page 
views.TeacherDashboard run the query and i pass it to render function but in response this issue comes

Comment: Show us the entire **teacher_dashboard.html** or at least all the `{% url ... %}` tags in it.

Comment: in addition to previous comment - you have double slash in your second route address.

Comment: Also what you're showing cannot be your real code. The `TeacherDashboard` view requires an id but your url doesn't pass it. And your request was for `/teacher_dashboard/4` for which there is no url defined.

Comment: plz check that page i have uploaded

Comment: Why are there two teacher_dashboards.html?
Did you declare id in your model as a string or are you perhaps looking for the uuid or int type?

Comment: im sorry i got it thanks bye the way

Comment: nope i was not doing that basically there is error in 'teacher_dashboard.htm' page. i have there two links which are not mention in the url patteren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateorder` function in these links does not exist in your `urls.py`

```
<td><a href="{% url 'updateorder' order.id%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</a></td>
<td><a href="{% url 'deleteorder' order.id%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Remove</a></td>
```

Create the function in your views and reference it in your urls file.